# Exception: Unable to retrieve security descriptor for this frame exception

Tags: .net

The exception from the subject line is thrown when I am trying to load an XSL spreadsheet. The call stack is attached below. This program worked for a while with a variety of style sheets now it works on some comuters but throws this exception on some other. I looked it up on the internet but [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/xmlandnetfx/thread/c5ba915d-d35b-4170-96b1-fb2b107f8779) is all I could find and it does not give any answers other than some vague suspicion on some seciruty update. I am at loss. Any ideas?

```
at System.Security.SecurityRuntime.RevertAssert(StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
at System.Security.CodeAccessPermission.RevertAssert()
at System.Xml.Xsl.XmlILGenerator.Generate(QilExpression query, TypeBuilder typeBldr)
at System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform.CompileQilToMsil(XsltSettings settings)
at System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform.LoadInternal(Object stylesheet, XsltSettings settings, XmlResolver stylesheetResolver)
at System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform.Load(XmlReader stylesheet)
at AIM.Letters.Documents.Layout.get_WordXsl() in c:\AIM\LettersSolutionII\LetterDocuments\Documents\Layout.cs:line 29
at AIM.Letters.ProcessingService.Activities.TiffGenerator.BuildWordML(LetterJob jobDocument, Layout layout) in C:\AIM\LettersSolutionII\LetterService\Activities\TiffGenerator.cs:line 253
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like my problem was related to a discreapncy in .NET dll versions, specifically the System.XML.dll. The computers which have .NET Framework 2.0 Service Pack 2 installed are working ok. The ones without this service pack are misbehaving. It is still a mistery for me how my older code was working with "bad" System.XML.dll